# No output from glDrawElements with IVA

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I am writing an opengl program in cocoa and I having trouble rendering using interleaved vertex arrays. Opengl is setup using a NSOpenglview, and specific rendering is done by individual objects. Rendering works with a static 'cube' object that is set up similar to the following code, but does not use indexed drawing or an iva.

My initialisation code

```
    node = [[Octnode alloc]initWithTreeHeight:0 nodeSize:1.0 orign:&origin memoryPointer:vertexData];

    indexArray[0] = 0;
    indexArray[1] = 1;
    indexArray[2] = 2;


    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36 * sizeof(unsigned int), indexArray, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(vertexArrayObject);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(colouredNormalVertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(colouredNormalVertex), (void*)sizeof(vertex));
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(colouredNormalVertex), (void *) ( sizeof(vertex) + sizeof(colour)));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);

    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(0);
```

Rendering code
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(vertexArrayObject);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(0);

The data for the array is added is configured in the octnode init, and inspection with a bebugger shows what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

When providing data for the buffer, instead of passing in the size of the data I was passing the size of the pointer

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Should be, at a minimum

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(voxelData), vertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```